# 4.4 Real External SDCard in Emulator

Tags: android

If I'm not wrong android no more allows 3rd party apps to write inside real external SD card since Honeycomb(except own data folder provided by OS) ? But no hardware manufacture followed that in their devices. But now Samsung and LG seems to be using it from 4.4 (API 19) and because of that I'm receiving bug reports of permission denied. Or maybe Im wrong about honeycomb.

Since I need to test my app, I'm unable to create an emulator using real external SD Card. I mean the SD Card I created is emulated by device. Which android allows for all apps. Is there any way I can create something that emulator treat it as real external card ?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to emulate this using the standard Android emulator. You might see if Genymotion offers any options here.

Comment: Genymotion is doing same